# Cannot find proof that a Hotfix was installed

Tags: windows

I have a user that has an insanely large mailbox.  The user is getting the Outlook dialog box that shows a progress bar that is downloading external pictures

[image]

So I applied the Hotfix KB2883076 and KB2889859 that is supposed to just make the dialog box essentially invisible to the user.

My question is, how can I verify that these Hotfixes have been applied?

I have tried:

```
wmic qfe get | find "KBXXXXXXXX"

systeminfo | find "KBXXXXXXX"
```

PS:

```
Get-InstalledUpdates KBXXXXXXX
```

None of those report that the Hotfixes were applied.  I've even dug around in Programs and Features manually.  There's no record of it.

I installed the Hotfixes manually, with the GUI driving it and received no errors.  Event viewer does not report any errors regarding the update.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, the PS command was: Get-Hotfix -Id "KBXXXXXX"

Answer (score 1):

Check the Windows Setup event log, hotfixes are logged there during installation.

You can also check the file versions in the KB articles to see if they match the versions on the system.

Comment: I checked the Windows Setup event log.  There is no record of it installing there.  Are you referring to comparing file hashes?

Comment: Right-click on the files listed in the KB article, Details tab > File Version, and compare it with the version in the article.

Comment: File versions for the executable are the same as the ones listed in the KB Article.  Once it's extracted, it's a .msp file.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: So, still no record of it installed.  I am not sure what to do at this point other than install it and hope that it will just fix it.  I imagine that logging a ticket with MS is the next step.

Comment: If the files on the system are the same version or higher, the hotfix was installed or is not applicable.  Easy test: try right-clicking the msu file and select Apply.  If it says already installed or not applicable, nothing left to do.

Comment: Okay.  That is the same as running the program, but I did it.  Still no record of the KB install though.  I am just wondering why there isn't any feedback if the hotfix isn't applicable or already installed.  If I install it twice in a row, it states that it's already installed, but no errors or messages when running it the first time.

Comment: There you go, already installed.

Comment: Good enough for me.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If they are not showing up Windows Updates (and they should), then they have not been installed or installed completely.

The other guy is right though about checking the logs, it could give you an idea on why they failed.

Comment: This is the command I am using for the silent install:  msiexec /p C:\PathtoFile\mso-x-none.msp /qn and it completes successfully, no errors at all.  But I cannot find any record of that specific KB.